# Rails: how do you access RESTful helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

I'm trying to work through this [guide to Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing_outside_in.html), but I got stuck in section [3.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing_outside_in.html#_urls_and_paths):

> Creating a RESTful route will also make available a pile of helpers within your application

and then they list some helpers like `photos_url`, `photos_path`, etc.

My questions:

Where can I find the complete list of helpers that is "made available?"

Is there a way to call the helpers in the console? I created an app, then opened up the console with `script/console`. I tried to call one of the helpers on the console like this:

```
>> entries_url
```

But got:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `entries_url' for #<Object:0x349a4>
    from (irb):8
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have several questions in there, most of which have already been answered by people below.

The answer to one that wasn't fully addressed however, is: yes you can use the script/console to see where your routes go. Just type in `app.[route_helper]` and it will respond with the path. For example `app.users_path` will return `/users/`

So for your example type `app.entries_url` for the full URL - or `app.entries_path` for its relative path within the console.

Comment: the extra anchovies is that it does tab completion, e.g., at the console type app.edit[tab] and it lists all routing helper methods beginning with 'edit'.

Answer (score 18):

`rake routes` at the command line should get you that list.

Comment: Take the first column and append _url to have the full URI or _path to have an URI not including the domain name.

Comment: Is there any way to generate a list of helpers, with _url and _path and parameters written explicitly? Would be most helpful in the case of nested resources, to see clearly what parameters each helper takes, if any.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be what you are looking for ... http://topfunky.com/clients/peepcode/REST-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can access other helpers in the console by prepending "helper."; ie. helper.progress_box (assuming #progress_box exists of course)

Answer (score -6):

From memory, you can't call url/path helpers from the console for some reason.