# Why can't I output a path when in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried doing this when in rails console:

puts about_home_index_path

It gave me an erorr, why is that? should it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was answered here: [Rails: how do you access RESTful helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433860/rails-how-do-you-access-restful-helpers)

You should use:

`puts app.about_home_index_path`